# Builder lacks artifacts concordance improvement?

Tags: dnd-4e, dnd-4e-character-builder

I'm facing a problem with the artifacts concordance of the D&D4 character builder. I wasn't able to find a way to level up the concordance. The +5 sword nightbringer at the top concordance level becomes a +6, but the builder doesn't show this so I have to manually manually print and correct the sheet marking the new powers.

Is it a bug or am I missing some feature or similar?

Comment: Likely, you'll have to print the item's sheet from the compendium and keep it on hand. Same goes for item sets.

Comment: Artifacts are unfortunately one of the areas where the CB didn't get quite as much attention to niche cases as it needed. I suspect the programmers figured that since few DMs would give their characters artifacts, it wasn't worth implementing a concordance system.

Comment: Since it looks like it's a bug, you may want to report it. I don't see it on the "D&D Insider: Known issues list for Character Builder."

Answer (score 5):

From [Nightbringer](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=152),

> The sword Nightbringer is a +5 vicious longsword with the following
>   properties and powers.

Just add the +5 vicious longsword in the character builder and have the Nightbringer item description printed out with your character sheet. When you reach enough concordance for the artifact to increase its enhancement bonus to +6, you can just replace the +5 with a +6. Then all of the calculations are done for you and you won't need to make manual corrections on your character sheet.

The only drawback is that your equipment page won't actually show that you have Nightbringer equipped, but that seems like a small price to pay to avoid manual corrections.

Comment: Good work around.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to make a custom item card (as you are saying builder lacks an item card appropriate for the artifact) I would suggest [Power2ool](https://power2ool.com/login/)

Power2ool is a free, Flash based website that lets you create item and power cards just like the ones generated by the character builder. It color codes and formats the cards based off using keywords like, "Effect:" and "Hit:" and in the few instances where it doesn't know what to do automatically, can be tricked into formatting correctly.

Even more importantly, Power2ool arranges the power and item cards in order as if they were being printed out for a character sheet from the 4e Character Builder and has built in functionality to print these out on sheets of paper (or into adobe PDFs).

If you decide to use it, message me in chat for help as some of the syntax is finicky.